# Google Assistant is unable to accept voice input unless summoned via "OK Google," and even then only the first first action

Tags: google-assistant

I have a very strange issue that I haven't found anything else on. Most resources only cover enabling voice match, and issues with it not working specifically.

My issue is related, yet also very different.

See, if I open Google Assistant manually, either by selecting the Assistant app, or swiping from my bottom corner, it sits there waiting for voice input, but seems unable to detect anything that I'm saying. However, if I summon Assistant by using Voice Match by saying "Ok Google" or some variation thereof, it can detect and accept input as normal, but only for that specific interaction. If something requires multiple steps, for example, the "what song is this" command, it will detect the first instruction after being summoned by voice match, but then proceed to fail to detect any subsequent input.

I have an Asus ROG Phone 6 running Android 12. Issue persists across multiple restarts, and even uninstalls and reinstalls of Assistant. I've also tried deleting and recreating the voice profile to no avail.